# Declaring objects and printing strings in PHP

Tags: php, html, class

Catchable fatal error: Object of class HelloWorldClass could not be converted to string in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wisd_activity04c.php on line 19

This program is supposed to output 
1. "Hello World!" in red/40px font
2. "Hello World!" in green/20px font and underlined

```
<?php 
    echo '60-334 ACTIVITY 4 PART 3/3<br><br>';

    class HelloWorldClass
    { 
        public $font_size;
        public $font_colour;
        public $hello_string;

        function __construct($size, $colour)
        { 
            $this->font_size = $size;
            $this->font_colour = $colour;
            $this->hello_string = "Hello World!";
        } 

        public function custom_show() 
        { 
            echo "<font color=\"$this.font_colour\" size=\"$this.font_size\">$this.hello_string</font>";
        }  
    } 

    class Sub_HelloWorldClass extends HelloWorldClass 
    { 
        function __construct($size, $colour)
        {
            parent::__contruct($font, $colour);
        }

        public function custom_show() 
        { 
            echo "<u><font color=\"$this.font_colour\" size=\"$this.font_size\">$this.hello_string</font></u>";
        } 
    } 

    $object = new HelloWorldClass('40px', 'red');
    $object->custom_show();

    $object = new Sub_HelloWorldClass('20px', 'green');
    $object->custom_show();
?>
```

Comment: You've missed a semi-colon after `"Hello World!"`

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123, @hobo! I corrected that. But still the same error message!

Comment: Space in `Sub_ HelloWorldClass` => `Sub_HelloWorldClass`

Comment: If you've corrected that and you're still getting __the same__ error then you haven't corrected the file you're running. You probably have a __different__ error on line 23 where you have a spurious space in your class name.

Comment: @AnnieThiessen You can flag your own question if you think it should be reopend (Button bottom left of your question: `flag`-> other reason)

Comment: @HoboSapiens, I corrected the space in Sub_HelloWorldClass. Now the error message is  Catchable fatal error: Object of class HelloWorldClass could not be converted to string in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wisd_activity04c.php on line 19

Comment: Ok @Rizier123! I don't understand why it was closed

Comment: @AnnieThiessen Your question was closed because (in the words of the message above) _'the question was caused by ... a simple typographical error'_ This sort of syntax checking is considered off-topic. What's worse is that you have edited the code to correct the first error, but not edited the error message, so now your question makes no sense anyway.

Comment: @HoboSapiens I voted for reopen, because the question has different fatal errors in it, which shows misunderstanding from a few php operators and php syntax and i also guess OP is a C++ or Java or C# developer

Comment: @Rizier123 The question as originally posed was answered. The question as it now exists makes no sense. This should not be re-opened.

Comment: @HoboSapiens No it wasn't answered, not even half of it. This would show that you haven't spotted all errors

Comment: K, I was working on correcting that. Either way the question has been formatted now.

Comment: `$this.font_colour` → `$this->font_colour` – still just a typographical error.

Comment: @deceze And still not all errors are spotted in the comments! Also much more information to say/show OP. I think it's better to show OP now what he's doing wrong, instead of waiting to get a question every day for every single error

Comment: I agree with reopening the question. There are more errors in the code that needs to be tended to and not just typos.

Comment: The errors are too general. Missing semicolon? Wrong access of class property's? Class name with space? Please read tutorial & documentation first.

Comment: @AndrewT. Did you down voted my answer? (BTW: If you take a closer look there are a few points which let you think OP is a C++ or C# or Java developer, so he is mixing stuff form different program languages and i think it's very important to show and explain what he did wrong, so that in the future he doesn't mix programming languages anymore)

Comment: @Rizier123 no, the answer is okay. But this question won't be useful at all for future readers. I even doubt people will stumble upon this question and  get useful answer, if the problem is caused by syntax errors due to past experiences in other languages. Stack Overflow's mission is to be a repository of programming knowledge, not just to cater one person's issue (too localized).

Comment: @AnnieThiessen Where are we now with this question?

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for the help! I didn't log back in until today. The concept I didn't understand was accessing class properties and printing them in a string. Concatenation was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: In the future I'll make sure there are no typographical errors before I post. Obviously some people can't look past them and see the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This answer is from your first revision:

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28522294/1

You have a few errors in your code:

1. Missing semicolon

```
$this->hello_string = "Hello World!"  //<- Missing semicolon at the end
```

2. Wrong access of class property's

```
echo "<font color=\"$this.font_colour\" size=\"$this.font_size\">$this.hello_string</font>";
//...
echo "<u><font color=\"$this.font_colour\" size=\"$this.font_size\">$this.hello_string</font></u>";
```

I recommend you to concatenate the property's with the string. [How to concatenate?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) You have to use the concatenation operator: `.` and also determ the string with the quotes.

Additional to that you also have to access a class property with the operator: `->`. For more information about accessing class property's see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

So your code should look something like this:

```
echo "<font color=\"" . $this->font_colour . "\" size=\"" . $this->font_size . "\">" . $this->hello_string . "</font>";
//...                 ^ See here concatenation                   ^^ See here access of class property
echo "<u><font color=\"" . $this->font_colour . "\" size=\"" . $this->font_size . "\">" . $this->hello_string . "</font></u>";
```

3. Class name with space

You can't have a class name with spaces:

```
class Sub_ HelloWorldClass extends HelloWorldClass  //So change just remove the space
```

For more information about class names see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

And a quote from there:

> The class name can be any valid label, provided it is not a PHP reserved word. A valid class name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: **^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$**.

4. Missing 's' in `__construct()`

```
parent::__contruct($font, $colour);  //Missed 's' in construct
```

5. Wrong variable used

```
function __construct($size, $colour)
{
    parent::__construct($font, $colour);  //Change '$font' to '$size'
}
```

**Side Note:**

Turn on error reporting at the top of your file(s) only while staging:

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

This will provide you useful error messages which show's you very well where the error is!